# Проблема со списками и вложенными списками

Tags: python, list

Пишу небольшой консольный текстовый редактор. Программа собирает данные из файла и закидывает их в список построчно. Есть 2 функции: `deletecol()` - функция удаляющая колонку букв с номером, который указал пользователь и `undo()` - функция, которая позволяет откатить изменения. Функцию `undo()` я реализовал посредством буфера (filestatuses): он содержит изначальное состояние файла и все состояния файла после применения команд.
`undo()` должна брать из буфера предыдущее состояние файла и засовывать его в исходное состояние (currentfile), но на деле дебагер показал, что все работает нормально до выхода из `undo()`. После выполнения `undo()` сurrentfile сначала принимает предыдущее состояние файла, но после выхода из функции принимает в себя совершенно другое значение, к примеру после выполнения таких команд:

> deletecol1 deletecol1 undo deletecol 1

из текста

```
1111
2222
3333
```

получается 1 2 3, а должно быть 11 22 33
Я подозреваю, что я что-то напутал с поверхностным/глубоким копированием, но не могу понять что

```
filename = input("Введите полный путь к файлу")
f = open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
currenfile = [] #Создаем список для строк текущего файла
for line in f: #Закидываем строки текущего файла в список:
    currenfile.append(line.strip())
print(currenfile)
filestatuses = []#Создаем переменную для сохранений состояния файла после выполнения команды
filestatuses.append(currenfile.copy())#Закидываем туда изначальное состояние файла

def deletecol(num_col):
    for i in range(0,len(currenfile)): #удаляем букву в каждой строчке
        if len(currenfile[i]) >= num_col:
            currenfile[i] = currenfile[i][:num_col-1] + currenfile[i][num_col:]
    filestatuses.append(currenfile.copy())#полученное состояние файла добавляем в список
    print(filestatuses)
    print(currenfile)
    return

def undo():
    currenfile = filestatuses[-2].copy() #Не работает???
    filestatuses.pop(-1)
    print(filestatuses)
    print(currenfile)
    return

while True:
        command = input("Введите команду и её аргументы(если есть)через пробел: command command_arg1 command_arg2: ")
        command = command.split(' ')
        match command[0]:
          case "deletecol":
                if len(command) == 2:
                    deletecol(int(command[1]))
          case "undo":
                undo()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде возникает проблема с обновлением переменной `currentfile` в функции `undo()`. Проблема заключается в том, что по умолчанию Python считает переменную currentfile внутри функции `undo()` локальной переменной, поэтому изменения, сделанные внутри функции, не сохраняются в глобальной переменной `currentfile`.

```
def undo():
    global currenfile
    currenfile = filestatuses[-2].copy()
    filestatuses.pop(-1)
    print(filestatuses)
    print(currenfile)
    return
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое, не заметил такой глупости